# doctrine: call symfony method based on Entity DateTime age

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm new to Symfony and Doctrine.

I got a project where I need a method inside a Symfony service to be called with data from the DB whenever a dateTime object saved in that DB table "expires" (reaches a certain (dynamic) age).

As I'm just starting out I do not have any code yet. What I need is a start point to get me looking in the right direction as neither the life cycle callbacks nor the doctrine event listener / dispatcher structure seems to be able to solve this task.

Am I missing something important here or is it maybe just a totally wrong start to my problem which actually can't be solved by doctrine itself?

What came to my mind is a cron-job'ish structure, but that kind of implementation is not as dynamic as required but bound to specific time frames which may be not reactive enough and maybe even immensly decreases the performance in different situations.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your problem right: You want something that executes when a record's datetime expires.

The main problem is that you would have to call PHP based on a DB event which is not straight forward...

One possible solution can be a Symfony command that's executed periodically(using cron) and you select the expired entities and do the required actions.

Comment: That's what I was initially thinking aswell but I really need something that triggeres on the next second, when the dateTime expires. This would require to run a cron every second querying the whole db table to check for expired dateTimes and run the calculation required afterwords. That's not really a good idea performance wise IMO.

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I found out doctrine is really not able to do this task in the descriped way. Of course the DB can't react to a part of a record it saved without an external action triggering the lookup.

So what I will propably go with is a shell programm called `at`.

It actually is something like I (and katon.abel) mentioned. It is able to enter one time crons which are then executed according to the provided time (that I then do not need to save in the DB but just pass it to `at`).

This way I can easily create the crons via symfony, save the needed data via doctrine and call the callback method via a script triggered by `at`.